# Rewrite rule Apache to nginx

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, nginx

I need help from professionals :)
Can anyone tell me how to rewrite this rules from apache to nginx?

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z]{1,6})$ forum/?to=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{1,9})/start/(.*)$ forum/?uid=$1&adt=2&url=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{1,9})/(.*)$ forum/?uid=$1&adt=1&url=$2 [L]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

here you go..

```
rewrite ^/([0-9a-zA-Z]{1,6})$ /forum/?to=$1 last;
rewrite ^/([0-9]{1,9})/start/(.*)$ /forum/?uid=$1&adt=2&url=$2 last;
rewrite ^/([0-9]{1,9})/(.*)$ /forum/?uid=$1&adt=1&url=$2 last;
```

Comment: It works :) but nginx wants quotes.

rewrite "^/([0-9a-zA-Z]{1,6})$" /fly/?to=$1 last;

rewrite "^/([0-9]{1,9})/banner/(.*)$" /fly/?uid=$1&adt=2&url=$2 last;

rewrite "^/([0-9]{1,9})/(.*)$" /fly/?uid=$1&adt=1&url=$2 last;

thank you krish